# Strange Circular Buffer behaviour

Tags: c++, multithreading, circular-buffer

I implemented a single-producer-single-consumer lock-free Circular Buffer. The reference implementation is the one at: http://home.comcast.net/~lang.dennis/code/ring/ring.html (the Base-line implementation, the first listing from top).

**EDIT:** For reference the original code:

```
template <class T, size_t RingSize>
class RingBuffer
{
public:
RingBuffer(size_t size = 100) 
    : m_size(size), m_buffer(new T[size]), m_rIndex(0), m_wIndex(0) 
    { assert(size > 1 && m_buffer != NULL); }

~RingBuffer() 
    { delete [] m_buffer; };

size_t Next(size_t n) const 
    { return (n+1)%m_size; }
bool Empty() const 
    { return (m_rIndex == m_wIndex); }
bool Full() const
    { return (Next(m_wIndex) == m_rIndex); }

bool Put(const T& value)
{
    if (Full()) 
        return false;
    m_buffer[m_wIndex] = value;
    m_wIndex = Next(m_wIndex);
    return true;
}

bool Get(T& value)
{
    if (Empty())
        return false;
    value = m_buffer[m_rIndex];
    m_rIndex = Next(m_rIndex);
    return true;
}

private:
T*              m_buffer;
size_t          m_size;

// volatile is only used to keep compiler from placing values in registers.
// volatile does NOT make the index thread safe.
volatile size_t m_rIndex;   
volatile size_t m_wIndex;
};
```

**Mod**: I store read and write indices in local variables and use only the local variables in expressions. I update them before returning from the functions (get and put).

For clarity the get function:

```
bool Get(T& value)
 {
    size_t w=m_wIndex;
    size_t r=m_rIndex;
    if (Empty(w,r))
        return false;
    value = m_buffer[r];
    //just in case the compiler decides to be extra smart
    compilerbarrier();
    m_rIndex = Next(r);
    return true;
 }
```

Then, I created separate producer and consumer threads:

**Producer Thread loop:**

```
uint64_t i = 0;
while (i <= LOOPS) {
 if (buf.put(i)) {
  i += 1;
 }
}
consumerthread.join(); //pseudocode: wait for the consumer to finish
```

**Consumer Thread Loop:**

```
uint64_t i=0;
while (i < LOOPS) {
 buf.get(i);
}
```

Producer puts integers [0, LOOPS] into the buffer and the consumer gets them one at a time from the buffer until it finally gets the integer value LOOPS, and the consumer loop terminates. Please note that size of the buffer is much smaller than **LOOPS**.

If I keep the volatile keyword on for the read and write indices whole thing Works like a charm. The Consumer loop terminates and the producer returns.

But, if I remove the volatile keyword then the consumer never returns.

Strangely enough, This consumer loop terminates:

```
uint64_t i=0;
while (i < LOOPS) {
 buf.get(i);
 fprintf(stderr,"%lu\n",i);
}
```

And this one terminates as well:

```
uint64_t i=0, j=0;
while (j < LOOPS) {
    if(buf.get(i)) {
     j=i;
    }
}
```

What is happening? I compiled the code using gcc 4.8.4 with -O3 flag set on a 64-bit intel (i3) machine running Ubuntu.

Comment: Please post an SSCCE: http://sscce.org

Comment: Try with -O0 flag and report the results.I suspect buf.get() is getting optimized away

Comment: http://isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/ -- use atomics instead of volatile!

Comment: @ Pavan Manjunath Terminates.

Comment: Post the source code here. `volatile` is not adequate for multi-threading, as @JonathanWakely tells you.

Comment: @ Maxim Egorushkin Source code is available on Dennis Lang's website. I have already listed the changes. Producer and Consumer run in separate threads and the Producer waits for the Consumer thread to finish. The problem exhibits itself when I remove the volatile keyword and compile with -O3 flag. Problem disappears when no optimization is performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the issue only occurs when you remove `volatile`, the issue is most likely caused by a compiler optimization that optimizes away reads of m_wIndex in the reader thread.  The compiler thinks it knows everything that might change that value so there is no reason to read it from memory more than once.

Adding a call to fprintf defeats this optimization because it's possible that fprintf might modify that variable.

Adding `j` made your code more complicated and also seems to defeat the optimization.